# Using c# dataset to talk to a sql database

Tags: c#, .net, sql, dataset

I have a SQL Express database that I am trying to connect with using C# to SELECT, INSERT, and DELETE using a DataSet.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a good tutorial on how to do this? I have a simple database consisting of 2 tables, with a one-to-many relationship and a foreign key relationship.

I found the following on the MSDN website:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb655884(v=vs.90).aspx

I made some slight modifications to the above for use with Visual Studio 2010, but was unable to figure out how to use the DataSet once I created the datasource. The `dataset.xsd` and `dataset.designer.cs` files are added to the project upon completion of the wizard, but I can't figure out how to create a DataSet object and use it to talk to my SQL Express database.

Comment: there should be a generated xyAdapter-class. This is jused to fill the data into a dataset/table (with .Fill into a existing or .GetData to create a filled) - see my links below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one: [Working with Datasets in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bw9ksd6.aspx) there should be everything you need step for step. You can find everything you need to access the data with the generated DataAdapter here: [Populating a Dataset from a DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx)

Finally here is a complete [Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233773.aspx)

If you post some of your code I can try to help you further.